# How to get the tab-list class that is outside of the selector. I'm using the <input id="date-field"> as my this element

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="tabs-normal" class="tab-container">
  <ul class="tab-list">
    <li class="tab"><a href="#tabs-normal-notes">Notes</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-normal-notes" class="tab-panel">
    <h3>Notes</h3>
    <p> Post incentivize; rich-clientAPIs customized revolutionize 24/365 killer incentivize integrate intuitive utilize!<p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="date-field" class="label">Date Field</label>
                <input id="date-field" class="datepicker" placeholder="M / D / YYYY" name="date-field" type="text">
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <button type="button" class="btn-secondary" id="reset-form">Reset Form</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to get the 'tab-list' class outside of the selector. I'm using the **date-field** as my element. The .closest() and .find() are not working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. I already tried that @31piy. It still finds nothing..

Comment: post your code in JSFiddle or something

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/an6y82qo/1/

Comment: I want to get the 'tab-list' class using the 'date-field' as my element.

Comment: what you need exactly, you want to when click the date input fields and open the date picker calendar...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can try this.

$('#date-field').parents('#tabs-normal').children('ul.tab-list').addClass('chirag');
```

This is work for me.Hope also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by getting the tab-list using `date-field` as element.

Following is a way to get the `.tab-list` element if you have a reference of `#date-field` element.

```js
var dateField = $('#date-field');
var tabList = dateField.parent('.tabs-normal').find('.tab-list');

console.log(tabList);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-normal" class="tab-container">
  <ul class="tab-list">
    <li class="tab"><a href="#tabs-normal-notes">Notes</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-normal-notes" class="tab-panel">
    <h3>Notes</h3>
    <p> Post incentivize; rich-clientAPIs customized revolutionize 24/365 killer incentivize integrate intuitive utilize!
      <p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="twelve columns">
            <div class="field">
              <label for="date-field" class="label">Date Field</label>
              <input id="date-field" class="datepicker" placeholder="M / D / YYYY" name="date-field" type="text">
            </div>

            <div class="field">
              <button type="button" class="btn-secondary" id="reset-form">Reset Form</button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```